# Time complexity for a variation on the hailstone sequence?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

Consider the following code segment.

```
    Looping(n) 
      {
       while (true) {
         if (n <= 1) then return;
          else if (n mod 3 = 0) then n = n * 5 + 1;
         else n = n/9; // integer division
      }
```

What is the worst case time complexity of this code segment? `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One important observation we can make about this code is that after any two steps are taken, the size of n will decrease by a factor of (roughly) 2/3.  Here's why.  Consider any initial value of n and look at the remainder modulo three.

- If the remainder is one or two, we divide n by nine and round down.
- Otherwise, the remainder is 0.  Setting n = 5n + 1 now leaves n with a remainder of one, so on the next iteration we will divide it by nine.  The new value of n is then the floor of (5n + 1) / 9, which is (roughly speaking) 5/9ths the original value.  It's certainly no more than 2/3s of the original value.

Therefore, we get that this will terminate after O(log n) steps, since each iteration decreases n by some constant factor.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is it guaranteed that this code will terminate given any value of n?

Comment: I think that as long as n starts off nonnegative, it should.  Each step of either "divide by nine" or "5n + 1, then divide by nine" strictly decreases the value.  Or at least, I think it does...

Comment: Ah yes, you're right.  Since you're dividing by 9 the sequence will decrease at least every two steps.  The Collatz conjecture only divides by 2, so it doesn't have this property.

Comment: @templatetypedef If it's negative, the `n <= 1` condition kicks in.

Answer (score 1):

It's O(log(n)). Every time you do a 5n+1 you follow with a divide by 9 (since 5n+1=1 mod 3 if n=0 mod 3), so at the worst you're doing (5n+1)/9 every two steps, which is less than 2n/3 every two steps. This is O(log(n)). If it happens that n mod 3 is never 0, then you're dividing by 9 each step, which is also O(log(n)), just with a different constant.

So whatever n is, you're going to take O(log(n)) steps to get to 1 or 0.